# CSS doesn't render on `npm run start` command

Tags: css, npm, webpack

When I run `npm run start` for my project, my HTML and JS work great, but my CSS does not render. Screenshot below.

[image]

I bundled using webpack. I'm absolutely certain (and double checked) that my style.css file is linked in my index.html file.

My webpack.config.js file is below - could the issue lay there?

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/js/index.js'],
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    filename: 'js/bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  },
  plugins: [
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'index.html',
    template: './src/index.html'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader:'babel-loader'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

File Path:

[image]

Comment: Is it linked in the compiled html too?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. How would one go about checking? I scanned my bundle.js but couldn't tell.

Comment: I have not used the html plugin for webpack before but in the docs they say it generates an html with everything linked in from your bundle, is that right?

My idea is that your link could have been deleted by webpack as it generated the new html because you haven't specified anything css related in your config file. 

I'm not too sure tho.

Comment: @DylanCole Open the page where the error occurs in a Browser (Chrome/Firefox). Open the dev tools (ctrl-shift-i). Open the network tab. Reload the page (ctrl-r). Check if any network requests produce a 404.

Comment: @madflow Yeah - I get several 404 errors. I think it's a file path issue. I just added a picture of my file path in the original question.

Comment: Post the content from `src/index.html`. How do you `import` the css files? There is no loader configured and no Copy Plugin or anything...